# Question about a possible consequence of Sobolev inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces

I  would like to know if there is a result like this:

> Given $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^d$ a bounded domain where we can apply Poincaré and Sobolev inequalities, we consider $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{| \partial\Omega}=0$. Prove that there exists a constant $C$ non depending on $d$ such that
> $$d\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^2\leq C \sum_{k=1}^d\int |\partial_{x_k}f|^2dx_1\dots dx_d,$$
> where $p=\frac{d-2}{2d}$.

**My attempt**

By sobolev embedding I know that there exists $C=C(p,d)$ such that $\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}$, with $p=\frac{d-2}{2d}$. Now, if we use the Poincaré inequality we obtain  a new constant $C=C(p,d)$  such that $\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C \|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} $.  Does anyone know how to conclude from here or a different proof of this result?

Comment: Poincare inequality is $\|u\|_{W^{1,2}}\le c \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$. If you combine Sobolev and Poincare you get the claim. Basically your attempt is already the proof. Nothing is left to show.

Comment: The problem is that in my attempt the constant $C$ depends on $d$. Furthermore, I don't obtain the factor $d$ in the left hand side as I desired